# Mocked instance fires events

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a class which I want to unit test and it has a dependency Foo, which I want to mock. This class Foo sometimes fires events when a certain method is called. But don't know how to mock the class Foo to get this behaviour.

So, how could I mock the class Foo, that it act like the following code? I used so far Mockito but open for new frameworks if mockito don't offer the needed functionalities.

```
//This is how the class Foo should act when it is mocked
public class Foo()
{
    private Listener listener;
    public void addListener(Listener listener)
    {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public void callMethodWhichMayFireAnEvent()
    {
        listener.event();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want the actual event to be fired by your test code? Othewise in Mockito you need to mock Listener which will not call the actual listener.event() it will be mocked.

Comment: Yes I want to fire an actual event to test my class if it react correctly.

Comment: Then either use stub (I  am not sure whether it will fire actual event) or use the simple JUnit where you create instance of class Foo and use it in your test cases.

Comment: So mocking is not the way to go in this case?

Comment: How are you using Foo?

Comment: My class which I want to test use foo and will call `addListener()` first to add the listener and later `callMethodWhichMayFireEvent()` which will fire somethimes an event to the registered listener (which is actually the class I want to test).

Comment: If the listener is what you want to test why are you mocking Foo? And why not the Listener?

Comment: Maybe I missunterstood something, but I should mock dependencies (in my case Foo) and not the class to test, not?

Comment: If the listener is what you want to test why are you mocking Foo? And why not the Listener? Also whether to use Mockito or not it depends the type of testing you want to carry out, you want unit testing I would suggest to use Mockito or integration testing use the good ol way i.e. create an instance of Foo and inject all actual dependencies and then write test for it.

Comment: No you need to mock the dependencies which are inside the ClassToBeTested and not in anyother class, i..e you want to test Listener you mock dependencies inside Listener.

Comment: Ok, I think I was not enough clear what I am doing. Listener is an interface which is implemented by the ClassToBeTested and Foo is used by this class.

Comment: If you need to test if your listener works, then you cannot mock it. If you do not need the listener behavior for your test, you can mock it and then just verify that the method `event` of your mocked listener was actually called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get what you ask for (which may or may not be what you actually NEED), you could use an answer...

```
   final Listener listener = ...; // put your listener here
   Foo fooMock = Mockito.mock(Foo.class);

   Mockito.doAnswer( new Answer() {

    @Override
    public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        listener.event(); // this calls your listener
        return null; // actual Method is void, so this will be ignored anyway
    }

   }).when( fooMock.callMethodWhichMayFireAnEvent() );
```

So, whenever `fooMock.callMethodWhichMayFireAnEvent()` is called, it will call the `event()` method of your `listener` object.

Comment: Well, I think that is what I need and (at least) tried to ask for :-)